# Container Engine: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Credentials'

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following the "hello wordpress" example:
https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-wordpress, but it stops with:

```
henrik_ormasen_gmail_com@k8s-test2-master:~$ gcloud alpha container kubectl create -f wordpress.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 209, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 205, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 537, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1073, in Run
    last_group = context_filter(tool_context, Http, args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/../share/google/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 458, in ContextFilter
    group.Filter(context, args)
  File "/usr/local/share/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/container/commands/__init__.py", line 61, in Filter
    credentials=cli.Credentials(),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Credentials'
henrik_ormasen_gmail_com@k8s-test2-master:~$
```

I also get this error running most other kubectl commands. And also `gcloud alpha container clusters create`

I've also tried: `gcloud auth login` without help. What are I missing?

```
henrik_ormasen_gmail_com@k8s-test2-master:~$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.61

alpha 2015.05.19
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
compute 2015.05.19
core 2015.05.19
core-nix 2014.12.17
dns 2015.05.19
gcloud 2015.05.19
gcutil 1.16.5
gcutil-nix 1.16.5
gsutil 4.12
gsutil-nix 4.7
kubectl 
kubectl-linux-x86_64 0.17.0
sql 2015.05.06
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your gcloud installation somehow got into a partially updated state. If `gcloud components update` doesn't do anything, try [reinstalling](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/#Quick_Start).

Comment: (Reinstalling fixed it)

Comment: for me as well!

Comment: Not for me: attempting to install got me: `ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.`

Comment: @tgf your system is MacOS?

Comment: @tgf okay, if it is then you should try `brew upgrade python2` - upgrade to 2.7.17 worked for me (gcloud version was 270.0.0)

Comment: @NULL - I'm on OSX and Python 2.7.17.  I `brew uninstall openssl
brew install openssl` and eventually got it working.  Somewhere along the way this also tanked my ruby installs.  My coworker ended up with the exact same problem so this may be tied to a recent brew update, not sure.