# Errors running gcloud, was working fine till yesterday

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, gcloud, hashlib

Yesterday, gcloud was working completely fine. And today, it's throwing this error. I'm quite sure I haven't changed anything to cause this. Does anybody have any idea what this could be?

1) I've exported `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` to be the `python2` path. I can't find the folders where gcloud is installed, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk) and so I'm a little lost. I've pasted the entire output.

2) I've tried reinstalled `openssl`, and unlinking and relinking it. That hasn't seemed to work either.

```
daudnadeem:an-pipeline-test daudn$ gcloud info
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: 'module' object has no attribute 'sha256'
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.api_lib.iamcredentials import util as iamcred_util
    from googlecloudsdk.api_lib.util import apis_internal
    from googlecloudsdk.core import properties
    from googlecloudsdk.core import config
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import files as file_utils
    class Checksum(object):
    def __init__(self, algorithm=hashlib.sha256):

This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.

Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.

If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

Any ideas as to what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having problems with this in the future follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39961195/11317776) guy's post. Initially, I thought it was super bad all of my brew packages were being upgraded, but it has managed to work. Not too sure how something can just stop working without any external factors.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you made no changes, but have you updated any packages or added new libraries?

I've found 2 SO threads with similar or the same issue that might help you out to check and see if those are your issues.

1. A file being in the way when you are attempting to import hashlib. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484179/11928097)
2. Another possible cause seems to be that gcloud got stuck into a partially updated state as this thread mentions a similar issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415408/11928097)

If it was happening to me I would try to reinstall the gcloud SDK or reinstalling python 2.

Let me know and if that doesn't solve it we can look deeper into it.

EDIT: I was typing this as you found the solution. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Last thing i did yesterday before leaving the office was ssh into my VM using `gcloud` and exit. And first thing I did this moring, was try the same and couldn't with the following errors. Maybe I changed something, but I'm quite certain I did not. I've got it working, but it was confusing nonetheless